# Extendable functionality for pluggable options in C#

Tags: c#

I was interested in how the following should be approached from both a pragmatic and pattern oriented design. I'd rather a real world answer over "pattern correct".

Simple Example:
Say I want an event logging system where developers just call the log method and provide a custom tag just so it prints out as a prefix to the error.

```
IEventLog eventLog = new StandardEventLog();
eventLog.LogData("trace data", new TraceLogType());
eventLog.LogData("error data", new ErrorLogType());
```

where the above is defined as such.

```
public interface IEventLog
{
    string Log { get; set; }
    void LogData(string log, EventLogType type);
}

public class StandardEventLog : IEventLog
{

    public void LogData(string log, EventLogType logType)
    {
        Log += logType.Type + ": " + log;
    }

    public string Log { get; set; }
}

public abstract class EventLogType
{
    public abstract string Type
    {
        get;
    }
}


public class TraceLogType : EventLogType
{
    public override string Type { 
        get 
        { 
            return "TRACE"; 
        } 
    }
}

public class ErrorLogType : EventLogType
{
    public override string Type
    {
        get { return "ERROR"; }

    }
}
```

It seems the overhead for such a small example of having to define a new ErrorLogType and instantiate it every time for use is a bit much.

Comment: If the problem is so simple as the example, why not using enum or even constant strings in some static structure

Comment: You should use polymorphism when you want the same interface but with different behaviour. If you just want a different value, make a new instance.

Comment: I agree with @djvuk, this is a lot of code, maintenance, and confusion to standardize words like "TRACE" and "ERROR". Either use an Enum as suggested, or have different methods, like `IEventLog.Trace(...)`, `IEventLog.Error(...)`, `IEventLog.Info(...)`, etc. I'd argue for the additional methods since it makes the code easy to understand the purpose, and allows different loggers to implement them differently. (For example, a logger that only emails "Error" level events to a team).

Comment: @djvuk: I guess the OP is after a extendable solution which follows the OCP.

Comment: Sorry it would have been better if I had stated and OCP compliant design as @DocBrown stated. I understand in this situation it is convoluted and confusing, thanks for the input all :)

Answer (score 2):

If the intent is to be able to add a "custom prefix" to a message, the real world solution would be something like this:

```
logger.LogData(String.Format("{0} {1}", prefix, message));
```

There is not much of a reason to get any fancier than that.  Using an enum doesn't make much sense since an enum is meant to constraint values and you want something open-ended.  Defining a class just for this is even worse.

Now on the other hand, if you don't want a custom *prefix* but in fact want a custom *log level*, that is a different matter.  The real world solution is: Don't do it.  There are too many external systems (e.g. log aggregators like SPLUNK, or employees in your operations command center) who rely on those values.

If you do find that the standard log levels don't work for your organization (and are willing to train everybody on your new fancy levels and customize all your logging and alerting infrastructure), come up with some new ones and hardcode them.  Yes, hardcode them.    The log levels are part of a logical interface, and of course you would never softcode an interface definition, because that would defeat the whole purpose of having an interface.

If you need some way to include custom text in your log messages, your [hardcoded] interface can include some flexible fields in it, e.g. a freeform string parameter which is inserted in a predetermined part of the message, if you think it is worth the extra complexity and you need the custom text to be placed in the same location every time.

The idea that your individual devs ought to have the ability to define custom log levels on the fly as they program, and furthermore that it should be easy, is IMO completely wrong.  They need to learn to log within the constraints they are given.  If an additional log level is truly needed, it *should* be difficult to add it, because you want it done only very rarely and in lockstep with other systems or personnel that may depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good start.  Then any specific implementation can hide the details of how it's logging and formatting the messages it's logging.

```
public enum MessageType
{
    Debug,
    Info,
    Warning,
    Error
}

public interface Logger
{
    void Log(string message, MessageType messageType);       
    void Log(Exception exception); //Assume message or error for exceptions.
}

public interface IMessageFormatter
{
     string Format(string message, MessageType messageType);
}
```

Comment: This solution is not extendible in the sense the OP was probably after: you cannot put this code into a library and extend the message types "from outside", as a user of that lib, without changing the lib intself.

Comment: There are only so many message types.  I guess if you wanted it extendable, you could add a "prefix" parameter to the formatter and expose that.  Or they could just build the string with the prefix in it and prior to passing it to the logger.  Internally the logger would use the formatter to tag the event with a date, etc.  which would be hidden from the callers.

Comment: I agree with what you were going for @Jon Raynor and agree that in this situation maybe OCP wasn't the best solution, possible some strategy pattern plug and play but you are right, for such simple functionality an enum with predefined list or possibly an xml reference to a list of a predefined list would make more sense. Thanks for your time to answer this question

Answer (score 0):

I propose creating a static `Trace` class in such cases, which can be shared between projects. That class can instantiate the appropriate `IEventLog` in your specification. Such a class can have methods such as `TraceError` or `TraceInfo` (choose appropriate names).

Note that such a pattern will also take away dependency of the consumer code away from `TraceLogType` and `ErrorLogType`, which is good because you can change the concrete implementations later.

This allows using configuration files to have `Trace` class change the actual instance of `IEventLog` based on configuration. Technically, you could base it as a strategy pattern. Even if the `IEventLog` instantiation is embedded in `Trace` class' code, it can be changed without modifying all the calling code.

This pattern will also avoid initialization of TraceLogType, ErrorLogType and IEventLog in multiple places in consumer code.

For your example, this is what such a class might look like:

```
public static class Trace
{
    private static IEventLog logger = new StandardEventLog();
    private static TraceLogType traceLogType = new TraceLogType();
    private static ErrorLogType errorLogType = new ErrorLogType();

    public static void LogTrace(string message)
    {
        eventLog.LogData(message, traceLogType);
    }

    public static void LogError(string message)
    {
        eventLog.LogData(message, errorLogType);
    }
}
```

This allows you to change virtually everything about your logging classes without impacting calling code. But if you need to pass a decision about how to initialize trace, an additional pattern is to add an `Initialize` method that can take appropriate parameters to make decisions about how to initialize.